# Incorporate Tabulator in postcss project

Tags: laravel, sass, tabulator, postcss, scss-mixins

We have a project that is uses postcss. Now we want to uses tabulator in our project but the tabulator uses scss and sass. So how do we incorporate tabulator in our postcss project?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your existing webpack configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using NPM to pull in tabulator as a dependency you simply need to use an import statement in one of your files to pull in the Tabulator CSS that is compiled in the dist folder, you shouldn't need to pull in the SCSS directly at all:

```css
@import "~tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.css";
```